# selecting an icon using query selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I found this code online a couple weeks ago. and what it does is, it selects the like button icon under a youtube video and then clicks on it.

```
likeButton = document.querySelector('#icon[alt^="like this"]').parentNode.parentNode.parentNode
likeButton.click();
```

recently, youtube changed their UI and i'm assuming their code changed, so this doesn't work anymore, I was also dumb enough to never understand and research the code.

I was wondering if someone could help me understand this part `'#icon[alt^="like this"]'`,

what does the `alt^=` mean and where would I go looking for the icon name "like this"

thanks for your help

Comment: `<img id="icon" alt="like this one">` <- that's where the `alt` is, and the `^=` means "starts with".

Answer (score -2):

It looks like they took the `alt` tag off of that button. I would target it with `title="I like this"` attribute of the button.

Comment: I'm looking in the elements section, and I can't find a title of "I like this" only a hidden tool tip with those words, did you find it in there?

Comment: I found "I like this" on the thumbs up button.